# Making a view block display link

Tags: views, blocks, 6

I'm currently migrating a website from Drupal 5 to Drupal 6. I've migrated most of the modules but something keeps nagging me: on Drupal 5 I had a block that displayed a snippet of text with a "More" link in a separate line. This snippet of text sent the user to a page with the full text.

After the Drupal 6 migration that snippet of text no longer links to anything. How can I make it lu

Comment: In your block, do you still have the "more link" set ?

Comment: I do. The More link works but the link that spanned the whole snippet of text is gone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, how was built the link ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's just there on 5. I've been through the source on both 5 and 6 and I see no changes.

I wonder if this is related to any changes in the way views work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by going to Views, selecting this particular view, selecting Block display and in the Field section editing the Node: title checking the box labelled "Link this field to its node".